# UITableViewCell row action while table is editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a UITableView which I need to both reorder and allow for cells to be deleted by swiping left on a cell to reveal the Delete action. Is it possible to have both at the same time?

For the table I have:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
tableView.isEditing = true
```

For the datasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // I do nothing here
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // This is where I rearrange my data source array
}
```

And for the delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Remove") { action, index in
        // delete row
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.appRed

    return [delete]
}
```

So what I want to have is:

- Reorder control allowing me to move a cell
- Swipe left to reveal cell actions

And I need these to be visible and work at the same time. Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried using the new iOS 11 `UITableView` Swipe Actions delegate methods? This is not something I have used, as yet, but may be what you need. Blog post (but there are many others): https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/uitableview-swipe-actions-in-ios-11/

Answer (score 2):

*Swipe to delete* is **not** possible when your `UITableView` is in editing mode.

If you want to hide the delete button on the left when in editing mode you have to implement the following methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return tableView.isEditing ? .none : .delete
}
```

I think this is the closest you can get.

Comment: And there is absolutely no way around that? :)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Horea as said it is **not** possible.  You can always develop your own solution if you want to rewrite the UITableView, etc.